# Converting string to HTML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, string

I am extracting content from an HTML textarea using JS, in order to then put it into a `<div>`. Now, I know the content is going to be valid HTML - so I assumed that if I set it as the innerHTML of another element it would be parsed by the browser - but it's not. I'm getting the plain string (with tags and all) on the screen.

This is basically my script:

```
var txt = document.getElementById("contentTextArea").innerHTML; //Get the content
document.getElementById("contentOutput").innerHTML = txt;
```

Here's the HTML, just to be sure:

```
<textarea name="content" id="contentTextArea">
<p>Text...</p>
</textarea>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way of doing this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textareas support `value` not `innerHTML`. YOu should do this...

```
document.getElementById("contentTextArea").value;
```

Answer (score 3):

`var txt = document.getElementById("contentTextArea").value;` //Get the content